# how to implement a simple tree using vector in c++ no binary or avl tree?

Tags: c++, tree

I have searched various sites but can't find any simple tree implementation.Please don't suggest a `BST` or `avl` tree and please implement your tree using vectors or arrays.

Comment: At least make an attempt at this before posting for help.

Comment: I smell homework.  If parent is at index X, say left child is at .2X, and right child is at 2X+1

Comment: it is not homework i was just doing practice

Comment: @rakshakpunia if you don't want a `BST` or an `avl`, what kind of tree DO you want?

Comment: i just wanted a simple tree i have tried making it with vectors but it is showing a lot of errors

Answer (score 1):

Create a standard binary tree, but use array (vector) indices instead of memory pointers.

```
struct Node
{
  Data_Item data;
  unsigned int index_left_subtree;
  unsigned int index_right_subtree;
};
```